# Who are “Security moms”?

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

I came across the word, “Security mom” and “Wal-Mart mom” in the following statement in my newspaper clippings, originally in *Time*: [Can Obama Win Back Wal-Mart Moms?](http://content.time.com/time/politics/article/0,8599,1839930,00.html)

> "The women that are different in some ways from their "soccer mom"
>   and "**security mom**" sisters of those earlier election cycles. They are
>   slightly older than soccer moms (in their 40s and 50s) and are
>   juggling another set of problems — how to pay for college for their
>   kids, how to take care of their elderly parents. They are also less
>   upscale. Lacking college degrees, Democratic pollster Celinda Lake
>   calls them "Wal-Mart moms" and "Wal-Mart grandmas" and says they are
>   not so much undecided as conflicted in making their choice this year."

The “Wal-Mart mom” is well defined in the above statement. I also know  “soccer mom," "tiger mom," and "helicopter mom.” But what is “Security mom”? Google search shows mosaic album of women under the heading of ”Security woman,” but it doesn’t give definitions of the word.

Is it associated with earlier Obama-care initiative? Is the word still current?

Comment: Why is it always the mothers and never the fathers who get "epitheted"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Interesting question, I'm sure it's partly because women generally take the lead in dealing with children and their activities, but it also seems a bit dismissive of their motivations. Apparently the Chinese have [Wolf Dads](http://thinkingchinese.com/wolf-dad-accompanies-tiger-mom-though-most-chinese-are-trying-to-escape-the-parenting-zoo) BTW, I'm a bit sorry I googled "tiger dad".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I had the same question and was attempted to add it to this question, though I didn't.

Comment: @Medica. Thank you for adding the source of the quote. I was surprised to find it was from Time September 9, 2008 issue. I was also amazed that you were able to locate such an old article. It looks a splended feat. Could you do it by just putting several key words?

Comment: If you search Bing or Google, etc for a portion of a direct quote, you can usually get a link to the *source,* which is what I labeled it in my answer. To find the Biden quote, just search for *security mom Biden.* Third, you can search Google Books for a phrase you are interested in, such as *security mom.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **security mom** is a mom whose main concern with regard to a political candidate (and by extension, his or her political party) is which one will do the most to protect her children from terrorism.

In this case the preceeding paragraph refers to what the writer means by *security mom.*

> ...The white female vote was crucial to George W. Bush's victory in 2004, a year that was marked by the post-9/11 political emergence of the so-called security mom — a term, interestingly enough, coined by Joe Biden...

[Source](http://content.time.com/time/politics/article/0,8599,1839930,00.html)

[Another article](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/oct/12/uselections2004.usa) contains the quote by Biden:

> In the post September 11 world, however, the soccer mom began to seem an anachronism. Democrat senator Joe Biden blamed his party's defeat in the 2002 midterms on its failure to listen to women. The agenda now was... "not schools, not prescription drugs. It was 'what are you doing to protect my kids against terrorists? Soccer moms are security moms now."

As for your two other questions,

> Is it associated with earlier Healthcare initiative? Is the word still current?

Nothing to do with healthcare.

Yes, it is still current. Such books as *[Women and the White House: Gender, Popular Culture, and Presidential Politics](http://www.kentuckypress.com/live/title_detail.php?titleid=2637)*, published in 2012, [use the term](http://books.google.com/books?id=1dKzvjjEJT0C&pg=PA85&dq=security%20mom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xYVRVLegJOGc8QGut4DwBw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=security%20mom&f=false).